# Saving contents of <pre> tag to file on server

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I have searched here and googled for this, and I've probably come across an answer, but I guess I don't understand asp.net enough to get it working.  As the title says, I'm trying to save the contents of a  tag to a file on the server.  I'm specifically using asp.net because I'm developing for a website on a WHS box and I'd like to use the already existing FBA.

Using javascript, I can successfully get the contents, but I am unable to work with it from there.  From what I've read, it sounds like I need to POST the contents, either a postback or to another page, to save the file.  That's what I'm having problems getting working.  I can get a StreamWriter created and working, but I am unable to pass what I need to it.

Thanks for any help, and I can post some of the code I have now if needed.  JR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Javascript to send an AJAX request to an ASHX handler with the text as the POST body.

You can then read the POST in the ASHX handler from the `Request` object and write it to disk.

Comment: Something similar to this? (Actually found on this site...)

`Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
Dim xmlFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()`